# Updating Products In Plugin

Tags: magento2, extensions, products

My main goal is to have a plugin which inserts/updates my products.

All my products are currently in a business management software database which I have SQL access for. What is the best way to go about this?

I guess what I'm looking for is how to add/update products inside of a plugin.

This it the current plan:

- Have the plugin code run on a CRON job
- Connect to the BMS and select the records (which will include the fields that the Magento Import system requires)
- Go line by line and either inserts or updates the record (guessing by checking if the SKU already exists)

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, describe your question in detail

Comment: I've updated my question with a plan of how I want the system to work which gives a better overview of what I want to achieve.